# How to fix error while installing wine, clamak, apache2 etc?

Tags: wine, apache2

How can I fix the following error while installing wine, clamak, apache2, etc?

```
error: "N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension 
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension"
```

Comment: the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck` is invalid. Either delete it or fix it so it points somewhere. It is not an ubuntu repo so ....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try moving or deleting "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck". It probably won't do any damage since it's a backup file.